# Submit when enter is pressed

Tags: php, submit

is it possible to have this form submit when someone presses enter

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= lang("reference_note", "reference_note");?>
    <?php echo form_password('reference_note', $reference_note, 'class="form-control kb-pad" id="reference_note" autofocus="autofocus"');?>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"> <?=lang('close')?> </button>
    <button type="button" id="suspend_sale" class="btn btn-primary"><?= lang('submit') ?></button>
</div>
```

the field requires input of a pincode and then when enter is pressed it should submit the form.
now the code is entered and it only submits when the button is pressed

Comment: `<button type="submit"` or input. should probably show us that unshown JS too. and form tags too probably, where are those?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of *"I'll ignore comments and just wait for answers"*

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JQuery?  If so, this will do the trick:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Otherwise, you can use pure javascript to accomplish it by doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitOnEnter(inputElement, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        { 
            inputElement.form.submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then on your input element, add this:

```
onkeypress="submitOnEnter(this, event);"
```